# Enable/disable textbox based on checkbox selection in WPF using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF form with as many as 40 textboxes, with a checkbox for each. Each textbox should be enabled/disabled based on the value of its corresponding checkbox. I've seen solutions where we can use `ICommand` to achieve this, but how do I handle 40 individual cases without having 40 `ICommand` implementations?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Just bind the `IsEnabled` property of the `TextBox` to the `IsChecked` property of the `CheckBox`:

```
<CheckBox Name="checkBox1" />
<TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=checkBox1, Path=IsChecked}" />
```

Comment: Yes, I just tried this after posting the question. This works for me. It's just that I was trying to avoid naming each checkbox to achieve pure MVVM, but I think I'll have to make an exception. Thanks.

Comment: I agree. Don't do this through MVVM. This enable/disable thingy is a pure User Interface design decision and has nothing to do with the underlying data of your application.

Comment: @Prakash: What makes you think that naming a checkbox isn't "pure" MVVM? Nothing in MVVM says you shouldn't give name to UI items...

Comment: @Thomas True. An ideal MVVM implementation wouldn't have any names for the data-bound controls. I realize that I can have names for the checkboxes as they're not bound to any data. What I require is pure UI functionality.

Comment: @Thomas, extending the same, how can I control the enable/disable of my textbox using a checkbox and a radio-button, both? My UI is such that the checkbox controls the individual textbox enable/disable, while the radio button controls the enable/disable of both the textbox and the checkbox.

Comment: If your checkbox and your textbox have a common parent panel, you can bind the IsEnabled property of the panel to the IsChecked property of the radio button

Comment: and what if you want the IsChecked = false disable the textbox ?

Comment: I mean if you want the textbox to be disabled When checkbox is  checked, and enabled when its not checked :) I am just wondering.

Comment: @Mark, you could use a [converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx)

Comment: yeah, I was just wondering if there was an easier way :) thanks.

Comment: @Mark, if you prefer, you could also bind to a property of the ViewModel, in which you can easily put any logic you want...

Comment: I tried it with Converter, it works, but as I am exploring, I thought about what you said, the problem is how I can control other controllers behaviour with this property u mentioned ?

Comment: @Mark, what do you mean by "control other controllers behaviour" ?

Comment: I mean (by the way, I am new to mvvm pattern, so trying to learn it) lets say I binded to a poperty of the viewmodel, how this property can control the textbox in this example depending on the checkbox status , how it can disale/enable it when the viewmodel has no idea about the controls ?

Comment: @Mark, you can do something like that: https://gist.github.com/thomaslevesque/3713bed71a486d02858a, bind `CheckBox.IsChecked` to `IsTextBoxDisabled`, and `TextBox.IsEnabled` to `IsTextBoxEnabled`

Answer (score 1):

if you have 40 controls like this, I would create a new control containing the checkbox and the textbox. The you can use that new control without the need to implement 40 commands, instead your new control has a single command implementation. and this is also less code to maintain as additional benefit